# SQL Server get concatenated number ranges (ISLANDS in sequences) from list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table structure:

```
DECLARE @headerTable TABLE (HeaderTableId INT)
INSERT INTO @headerTable VALUES (1), (2), (3)

DECLARE @detailTable TABLE (HeaderTableIdFK INT, DetailTableNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @detailTable VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,6), (1,7), (1,8)
                                ,(2,51), (2,52), (2,53),(2,100), (2,101), (2,102), (2,200)
                                ,(3,5), (3,6), (3,13),(3,20), (3,30), (3,51), (3,52), (3,53)
```

I have to get the following selection:

`HeaderTableId` , `NumberRanges`

'1', |||||||||||||||||||||||||| '1-3, 6-8'

'2',|||||||||||||||||||||||||| '51-53, 100-102, 200'

'3',||||||||||||||||||||||||||  '5-6, 13, 20, 30, 51-53'

I would prefer to get it all in one select statement, no aditional temporary tables.

Thank you!

Comment: @podiluska You do realize that I might not be familiar with the term gaps and islands in SQL, right ?
Plus that I have searched everywhere. I would not post to StackOverflow unless I had to...

Comment: Wouldn't the first record be `1-3, 6-8`?

Comment: @NickyvV Yes, my mistake. I will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT HeaderTableIdFK, DetailTableNumber, 
  DetailTableNumber 
   - row_number() over (partition by HeaderTableIdFK order by DetailTableNumber) grp
  FROM @detailTable
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT HeaderTableIdFK, min(DetailTableNumber) min, max(DetailTableNumber) max
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY HeaderTableIdFK, grp
)
SELECT HeaderTableIdFK,
    STUFF(( 
        SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN [min] < [max] 
          THEN CAST([min] as varchar(18)) + '-' + CAST([max] as varchar(18))
          ELSE CAST([min] as varchar(18))
        END
        FROM CTE2 t1 
        WHERE t1.HeaderTableIdFK = t.HeaderTableIdFK
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [NumberRanges] 
FROM CTE2 t 
GROUP BY t.HeaderTableIdFK
```

Result:

```
HeaderTableIdFK NumberRanges
1               1-3, 6-8
2               51-53, 100-102, 200
3               5-6, 13-13, 20-20, 30-30, 51-53
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 solutions for your issue.

First, try ['gaps and islands approach' totally described here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/condensing-a-delimited-list-of-integers-in-sql-server/).

Otherwise, concat the data without ranging, then apply some text-argument function to convert the list of 'id1,id2,id4' string into ranging 'id1-2, id4' string. To achieve this, use the following query and extend it with your text-argument function:

```
DECLARE @headerTable TABLE (HeaderTableId INT)
INSERT INTO @headerTable VALUES (1), (2), (3)

DECLARE @detailTable TABLE (HeaderTableIdFK INT, DetailTableNumber INT)
INSERT INTO @detailTable VALUES 
        (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,6), (1,7), (1,8)
       ,(2,51), (2,52), (2,53),(2,100), (2,101), (2,102), (2,200)
       ,(3,5), (3,6), (3,13),(3,20), (3,30), (3,51), (3,52), (3,53)

SELECT
    t1.HeaderTableId
        ,STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + cast(t2.DetailTableNumber as varchar(10) )
                        FROM @detailTable t2
                        WHERE t1.HeaderTableId = t2.HeaderTableIdFK
                        ORDER BY t2.DetailTableNumber
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                                      ,1,2, '' 
              ) AS ChildValues
    FROM @headerTable t1
    GROUP BY t1.HeaderTableId

-----
Output:
1   '1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8'
2   '51, 52, 53, 100, 101, 102, 200'
3   '5, 6, 13, 20, 30, 51, 52, 53'
```

Also, you could try [Tally table approach](http://sql-question.blogspot.ru/2012/10/what-is-tally-table-in-sql-server.html).